# Eldoc errors in Haskell Intero mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, haskell-stack, intero

I'm running Intero and Emacs 25.3.1 on a Mac. It was working fine until a few days ago. Now, every time I load a Haskell file I get

```
Error while checking syntax automatically: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p "Abort trap: 6")
```

I don't know much about Intero mode or Emacs debugging processes, so any help appreciated.